# Find JavaScript scroll top property without using .scrollTop?

Tags: javascript, scrolltop

Is There a way to find scroll top property with JavaScript without using `.scrollTop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED - measuring position in scrollable div using temporary element (as first-child) - this should not interfere with any styles as it is used only for measurement time:

http://codepen.io/themeler/pen/yOjXGp

Scroll position is saved in data attribute.

```
$(function () {

    function scrollMeasurer($elem) {
        var $measurer     = $('<div/>'),
            initialOffset = 0

        // measuring function
        function measure ($target) {
            var $m = $measurer.clone(),
                position = 0
            // prepend measurer
            $target.prepend($m)
            // calc position
            position = Math.abs($m.position().top - initialOffset)
            // remove measurer
            $m.remove()
            // save scroll position in data-attribute
            $target.attr('data-scrolled-value', position)
            // return position
            return position
        }
        // init (calculate initial offset)
        initialOffset = measure($elem)
        // recount when initial offset is calculated
        measure($elem)

        // bind measure on scroll
        $elem.on('scroll', function (e) {
            measure($(this))
        })
    }

})
```

Comment: In this way you find the y position of the element.I want to find scrolltop value

Comment: No,they are two different property.Or not? I know that they are different.

Comment: Both will return pixels scrolled from top.

Comment: So it's kinda same thing.

Comment: Good point. But you didn't mentioned what you want to measure.

Comment: I want to measure scrolltop value...the value of the scrolled part of a div

Comment: OK, you can actually do it using method above. Just change `k` position to `absolute` and append it to your scrollable div (must be `position: relative/absolute/fixed`). Now you can measure your scroll by finding `k.position().top` (it will give you negative value of scrolled pixels)

Comment: Ok,now I have understood.I have thought to do the same thing:append a child in the div and when on scroll event occurs take the offset top of the element that I have appended and the offset top of the scrollable div.Then make the difference between that two measures and find the scroll top value.Is it the same idea no?

Comment: If you append absolutely positioned element  (at `top: 0`) to your scrollable div (relatively positioned) you can check difference between those by jquery `position()` (it measures relatively). This will give you what you want. Offset will tell you always position measured from window, so it will be simplier to measure it by `position()`.

Comment: Yes,with position is simpler but the result is the same.One problem of your implementation occurs when div has only text.In that case position absolute div doesn't follow the scroll.i have thought to one simple div with no position that follow always the scroll

Comment: Obviously append the div like first child.What do you think?

Comment: You can to it relatively as long as box won't have padding.

Comment: Excuse me I haven't understood what you want to say

Comment: I've assumed you won't have elements in scrollable div, only text and its causing problem. As far as i checked (codepen demo updated) it does not break in this case. So I really don't understand problem now.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for your help:):)I appreciated it:)

Comment: I have found a bug in this solution.If css uses :first-child selector,with this implementation style will be changed when the div is added and this is not good...Is there an other way to do that?

Comment: You can just always put wrapper inside scrollable div (just plain, not styled div inside which you will place any of your content with any styles you want). And measure this div instead of dynamically added div saved under `k` variable. It will be most elastic solution i could think about if you don't know what will be inside your scrollable div.

Comment: Excuse me but I have not understood:(

Comment: Updated codepen. It just requires 2 divs and few lines of code. Now you can put every content you want with every styles you want inside.

Comment: Yes,yes:):)This is a good solution if I write the html of my div.What if i have to apply this function to an html that I have not written?This is my problem:)

Comment: If this is not embedded object you can modify it (or measure using existing html by modifying function). What are you really looking for? What divs you need to measure in this case?

Comment: I am trying to create a global function  that is able to find scrolltop value of all type of divs like the original function does

Comment: Maybe your function is able to do what I am looking for and I have not understood.Your function (like mine) works good with a self - written html.With other html it could not work well because the function is linked to a single structure of html...right?

Comment: You can do that with this solution and some modification. You will always need to target specific div, so you can cut it's content, place it in div ('scrollable-content' in example), and put back into scrollable div. The measurement method is in answer. You just always require parent with direct child that's not styled (so measurement will be accurate).

Comment: Yes but for example if the scrollable div has in css the selector :first-child all the style will be applied to div 'scrollable-content' because during the scroll this div becomes first child.Or not?

Comment: This solution will always require 1 element for measurement. It can be child, child-wrapper or pseudoelement. Sorry, but can't do it that way as you want. Updated codepen (but this probably wont fit your needs also).

Comment: I don't understand the first part of the function (befor the .onscroll).In that part what do you do and why?Sorry,I am  new with javascript and jquery.

Comment: Ok, got it! We just add measurer only for measurement time. So it won't interfere with styles. This should resolve your problem. Codepen updated. If you have further questions - ask.

Comment: Sorry but I haven't understood your logic.What change?

Comment: We are still adding element for measurement, but when we know position - we remove it. So you can't even spot it - it's like it never been added. So your styles remain as they were before.

Comment: Once we have added an element,it takes css style.How adding the element in your function it doesn't take style?

Comment: Is it a question of time?You remove it before css are re-read?

Comment: It's removed as fast as possible. Try in real case (you just place function in your code after document is ready and use on element).

Comment: So if the document is ready if I add an element,css won't be read again?

Comment: Oh god,I am becoming crazy:):):)

Comment: So the difference with the implementation done before regards only the time?

Comment: Before measure element was added permanently, now its added only for calculation. When you scroll or change in DOM everything is recalculated (its happening so fast that you won't see it, and you won't see your styles changing).

Comment: Ok,so the logic of the function is:I put the measurement element,I do the calculations and then I remove it.In this way the style changes but I don't see the difference because it is too fast...right?

Comment: Exactly like you said. Maybe (probably) there is rendering interval so it's not actually rendered (as you said before) but I don't have enough knowledge to be sure. Fact is that we're not seeing it so this assumption is probably right (when you have xx frames per second, such thing just have no room for being rendered).

Comment: Yes,I think it is like you said.Other two questions:why you use measurer.clone and why you save position in the attribute 'data-scrolled-value'?

Comment: 1. I create measurer div only once, so I it's a template, then I can just clone it and remove for each measurement. 2. I save position to attribute so you can check it with other functions when you need. You won't create special copy of this function for every div (counter in example is for example only) so you need to have place where each measured div save its scroll value.

Comment: I've updated function so it's now fully functional. As you can see, there is no problem with `:first-child` selector. Also, added initial offset measurement so if scrollable div has padding or border it will be taken care of be pre-measuring offset.

Comment: You measures initial offset of what?

Comment: Oh,I have understood:):)I have thought the same function initially but I haven't implented it because of the problem that I had seen of the :first-child selector.But this isn't a problem:):):)Thank you so much for your help and for your availability.I appreciated:):)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $("body").offset().top

Comment: I haven't understood your solution.How you can find a scroll top's value of an element with that code?

Comment: Can you be very specific about what you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question or what it is that you are trying to find as these two *should* work, but only if your target audience uses < IE9 would I go for option 2:

1. `window.pageYOffset`
2. `(document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop`

However, if you are trying to find the position of an element, read on.

---

```
function getOffsetY(elem) {

    var elem = document.body.querySelector(elem);

    return elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset - elem.clientTop;

}
```

Then `getOffsetY('#header')` or `getOffsetY('.footer')` will return the Y offset of any element passed in.

Here's an example:

```
var footerOffset = getOffsetY('.footer') + 'px';
```

Now `footerOffset` will give you the element's offset in `px` units.

---

[image: Explanation of code]

#### 1. window.pageYOffset

The amount of pixels the entire page currently has scrolled. You can also think of this as *"How many pixels do I need to scroll up to get to the top of the page?"*

#### 2. getBoundingClientRect().top

> [The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns ... its position relative to the viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

*Relative to the viewport* is key here. The viewport is the area of the web page that is currently visible.

`getBoundingClientRect().top` will include the size of the border and padding in pixels.

#### 3. clientTop

> [The width of the top border of an element in pixels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientTop)

If you wish to not take the size of the border into the calculation, you can subtract this from our result by using `clientTop`, as it will return the size of the top border.

Comment: Hi,what type of value will be found with this method?

Comment: @Fistright the Y-offset of the element passed into getOffsetY will be found and returned in pixels. You do have to add `px` to the end of the string in order for it to be used properly as a style. This is from jQuery's source, so this will save you from having to load the entire jQuery library for just a single function.

Comment: @Fistright I updated the examples, everything should be in there, whether you want to find the current page scroll position or to find the offset of an element. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: What i want to find is the scroll top: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

Comment: Is possible to find it with the properties that you have written or there is an other method(without using .scrolltop property)

Comment: @Fistright `var position = window.pageYOffset;` or `var position = (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop` should both work. Do you have a link to the page you want to apply this too?

Comment: Thank you so much for your support:)I want to find scrolltop 's value without using .scrollTop. I don't think that your solutions could help me.Maybe I am losing something in your reasoning?

Comment: @Fistright you're welcome, but what is stopping you from using `scrollTop` if I may ask? As I mentioned, `window.pageYOffset` will return the same value. :-)

Comment: Curiosity.I am curious to know if there is a way to find scrolltop value without using .scrollTop. I am curious to know how browser's programmers have implemented the function to find that value:)

Comment: Is there some way to do the function??I'm becoming mad:(:(

Comment: @Fistright I don't think that is possible as I think you are referring to Chrome's native code. See [this page](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/dom/Element.cpp), search for `scrollTop`. Is that what you are referring to? I'm not familiar with the inner workings of Chrome.

The `scrollTop`, `scrollY`, `pageOffsetY` methods are exposed for developers to use. I doubt that there is a better way of retrieving the current scroll position. The `getOffsetY` function I wrote above is similar to what jQuery internally uses. Did this answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

I thik you can this jQuery API,

https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

$( "p:last" ).text( "scrollTop:" + p.scrollTop() );

Comment: No,without using .scrolltop